# TexStudio 2.10.8 menu bar does not appear in Linux Mint

Tags: texstudio, linux

I use the latest distribution of TeXstudio by compiling the source package in Linux Mint manually. Recently I upgraded my system to 17.3 and my TeXstudio to 2.10.8, however, the menu bar is lost when I did this. Does anyone knows a solution to this?

Comment: In order to mark an answer as "Solved", please accept the appropriate answer by using the tick mark below the vote count of the appropriate answer.  Putting `{SOLVED}` in that title doesn't register the answer as being solved in the system.